# txAerospike - Aerospike and Twisted

Tags: python, twisted, aerospike

Is there a [twisted](https://twistedmatrix.com/) library for [Aerospike](http://www.aerospike.com/)? Has anyone used both in combination - or is Aerospike so fast that the [standard python client](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/client/python/) is enough?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Aerospike C client is very fast, but wrapping standard Python around it slows things down, mainly due to memory allocations and type casting.

I don't know of a project combining Twisted with the Aerospike client. Async functions are being considered but Python has different approaches to it from Twisted to gevent. We'd be happy to support such a project.

Answer (score 1):

When you're doing asynchronous network operations (like you do with Twisted) it shouldn't really matter how "fast" they are.

The usual approach for performing blocking calls from Twisted is running them in a thread ([example](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/gendefer.html#integrating-blocking-code-with-twisted)), for example with [`twisted.internet.threads.deferToThread`](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.threads.deferToThread.html).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11448033)

Comment: @Rogalski It is an answer. "or is Aerospike so fast that the standard python client is enough?" It doesn't matter. "Is there a twisted library for Aerospike?" You can call the regular library in a thread.